# Declaring Variables/Executing Functions Without Names

Tags: c#, shortcut

I couldn't really find anything on this, although I don't know exactly how to word it.

Are there drawbacks to writing something like this:

```
new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SomeFunction)).Start(SomeObject);
```

versus this:

```
ParameterizedThreadStart threadStart = new ParameterizedThreadStart(SomeFunction);
Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
thread.Start(SomeObject);
```

To me, if I don't ever need to call that thread again, then why do I have to even name it?

Comment: Nope. There aren't any, these two are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, no, however some reasons why you would want to use variables instead of inlining are:

- (obviously) if you wanted to reuse the value
- If the result implemented `IDisposable` (in which case you'd encapsulate it in a `using` statement)
- If one part of the compound statement could throw an exception that you could handle versus letting it bubble up.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it depends on whether the intermediary variables provide value to the future reader of the code.

In your case I don't see any trouble in keeping it compact because the intermediaries are only infrastructure code necessary to run `SomeFunction` on a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for

1. Better readability.
2. Maintenance of the code will be easy (for other developers)
3. and for exception handling (in some cases)

Otherwise both are equal.